# Multiple AND in where clause

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have made a query where i need multiple AND in WHERE clause? Where am i doing wrong?

`insert into payments(custom_file) value ('abc.txt') where orderid='1' and trx_id='123' and cust_id='1'`

Comment: are you sure you want to `INSERT` and not `UPDATE`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes i want to insert

Comment: @Thanga it says ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where orderid='1' and trx_id='123' and cust_id='1'' at line 1 `

Comment: Then using `WHERE` makes no sense, unless you are selecting values from a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND clause is for a WHERE clause (part of a SELECT statement). You are not making a SELECT, you are doing an INSERT.
Probably you like to do the following.

```
insert into payments(custom_file, orderid, trx_id, cust_id) 
value ('abc.txt', '1', '123', '1')
```

---

After the comment is clear that you like to do an UPDATE, not an INSERT.
Infact you like to **update** the column `custom_file` of a specific record

```
update payments set custom_file = 'abc.txt'
where orderid='1' and trx_id='123' and cust_id='1'
```

Comment: No man! i want to insert the file name where orderid,trxid and cust_id are as mentioned

Comment: So it is not an insert, but an update. I updated the answer, with that information

Answer (score 2):

There is no Syntax `insert into ...values ... where`What you Need is an update query i think.

```
update set custom_file = 'abc.txt' where orderid='1' and trx_id='123' and cust_id='1'
```